# Change Position of Object Python

Tags: python, pygame

I have a game I'm making on python and have a position of a paddle for air hockey, player 1 is on the cooridnates displayed below.

I cannot figure out how to position player 2 on the other side of the board in line with player 1?

```
player_1 = pygame.image.load(player1)
#tells you position of image
player1_position = [110, 150]
screen.blit(player_1, player1_position)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `player2_position = [some_x, some_y]` ? and don't forget to blit it

Comment: Why is this tagged with xcode?

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing, you want to plant the 2nd player on the opposite side of the field, correct?

```
player_2 = pygame.image.load(player2)
player_2_position = [BOARD_MAXIMUM_X - 110, 150]
screen.blit(player_2, player2_position)
```

before `pygame.display.flip()`.

For it to be "in line" The y or the x coordinate has to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, makes sense but what does BOARD_MAXIMUM_X  do?

Comment: Nothing, it's meant to be the maximum dimensions of your board in the x axis. It wasn't specified, so I left it as a variable.